# Add number of days to a date

Tags: php, date

I want to add  number of days to current date:
I am using following code:

```
$i=30;
echo $date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +".$i."days");
```

But instead of getting proper date i am getting this:
**2592000**

Please suggest.

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277247/increase-days-to-php-current-date

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692679/php-calculating-future-date-by-adding-days-to-a-variable-date

Comment: search using tag names with brackets around them, e.g. `[php] [date] add` in the search box.  You will find many answers to questions like this.

Answer (score 268, accepted):

This should be

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+30 days"));
```

`strtotime`

> expects to be given a string containing a US English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC), relative to the timestamp given in now, or the current time if now  is not supplied.

while `date`

> Returns a string formatted according to the given format string using the given integer timestamp  or the current time if no timestamp is given.

See the manual pages for

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

and their function signatures.

Comment: I think this will cause issues when crossing daylight savings times and other funny calendar items.  It sort-of depends upon the context. You need to think about if you are looking for 30 24 hour blocks, which, when crossing a daylight savings time day, might put you at 11:00PM.

Comment: @JJRohrer no, it won't. `strtotime` will take any DST for the configured timezone into account. DST is only an issue when you do something like this OP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066035

Comment: Point taken. I arrived at this Question trying to solve something a little closer to the question you referenced.  I hope my above comment with get others thinking about taking their date calculations seriously - its easy to forgot about all of the exceptions.

Comment: The original question was trying add 30 days to a variable date: $date but this solution adds 30 days to the current date.

Comment: @php-b-grader the question clearly states "I want to add number of days to *current* date" and the OP accepted it. So not sure your interpretation of the OP's intent holds up.

Answer (score 68):

This one might be good

```
function addDayswithdate($date,$days){

    $date = strtotime("+".$days." days", strtotime($date));
    return  date("Y-m-d", $date);

}
```

Comment: Above solution can be compacted in one line as well if you need a quick solution and do not want to create a function.
 
echo date("Ymd",strtotime("+12days",strtotime(20130101)))

Answer (score 50):

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('+1 week');
print $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

or `print date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(date("H"), date("i"), date("s"), date("m"), date("d") + 7, date("Y"));`

Comment: This method addresses crossing daylight savings time.  I'm not sure if  php accounts for other time quirks, like leap seconds, but, depending upon your needs, you are probably better off using DateTime vs. StrToTime if you dealing with calendar days.

Comment: @chx This solution also more carefully allows a date; e.g., new DateTime('2016-12-09 10:35:58'); that is coming from a database timestamp...

Answer (score 11):

```
$today=date('d-m-Y');
$next_date= date('d-m-Y', strtotime($today. ' + 90 days'));
echo $next_date;
```

Answer (score 10):

You can add like this as well, if you want the date 5 days from a specific date :

You have a variable with a date like this (gotten from an input or DB or just hard coded):

```
$today = "2015-06-15"; // Or can put $today = date ("Y-m-d");

$fiveDays = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime ($today ."+5 days"));

echo $fiveDays; // Will output 2015-06-20
```

Answer (score 7):

Keep in mind, the change of clock changes because of daylight saving time might give you some problems when only calculating the days.

Here's a little php function which takes care of that:

```
function add_days($date, $days) {
    $timeStamp = strtotime(date('Y-m-d',$date));
    $timeStamp+= 24 * 60 * 60 * $days;

    // ...clock change....
    if (date("I",$timeStamp) != date("I",$date)) {
        if (date("I",$date)=="1") { 
            // summer to winter, add an hour
            $timeStamp+= 60 * 60; 
        } else {
            // summer to winter, deduct an hour
            $timeStamp-= 60 * 60;           
        } // if
    } // if
    $cur_dat = mktime(0, 0, 0, 
                      date("n", $timeStamp), 
                      date("j", $timeStamp), 
                      date("Y", $timeStamp)
                     ); 
    return $cur_dat;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You could also try:

`$date->modify("+30 days");`

Answer (score 6):

You can do it by manipulating the timecode or by using [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). Here's an example using strtotime.

> $data['created'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+1 week"));

Answer (score 6):

You can use strtotime()
`$data['created'] = date('Y-m-d H:m:s', strtotime('+1 week'));`

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an old question, but for PHP <5.3 you could try this:

```
$date = '05/07/2013';
$add_days = 7;
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date) + (24*3600*$add_days)); //my preferred method
//or
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date.' +'.$add_days.' days');
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the DateTime class built in PHP. It has a method called "add", and how it is used is thoroughly demonstrated in the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

It however requires PHP 5.3.0.

Answer (score 5):

```
$date = "04/28/2013 07:30:00";

$dates = explode(" ",$date);

$date = strtotime($dates[0]);

$date = strtotime("+6 days", $date);

echo date('m/d/Y', $date)." ".$dates[1];
```

Answer (score 4):

You may try this.

```
$i=30;
echo  date("Y-m-d",mktime(0,0,0,date('m'),date('d')+$i,date('Y')));
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple and Best

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";
echo "<br>";
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', mktime(date('H'),date('i'),date('s'), date('m'),date('d')+30,date('Y')))."\n";
```

Try this

Answer (score 3):

Use this addDate() function to add or subtract days, month or years (you will need the auxiliar function reformatDate() as well)

```
/**
 * $date self explanatory
 * $diff the difference to add or subtract: e.g. '2 days' or '-1 month'
 * $format the format for $date
 **/
    function addDate($date = '', $diff = '', $format = "d/m/Y") {
        if (empty($date) || empty($diff))
            return false;
        $formatedDate = reformatDate($date, $format, $to_format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $newdate = strtotime($diff, strtotime($formatedDate));
        return date($format, $newdate);
    }
    //Aux function
    function reformatDate($date, $from_format = 'd/m/Y', $to_format = 'Y-m-d') {
        $date_aux = date_create_from_format($from_format, $date);
        return date_format($date_aux,$to_format);
    }
```

**Note: only for php >=5.3**

Answer (score 3):

```
//add the two day

$date = "**2-4-2016**"; //stored into date to variable

echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($date.**' +2 days'**));

//print output
**4-4-2016**
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code.

```
<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(' + 5 days')); ?>
```

Reference has found from here - [How to Add Days to Current Date in PHP](http://www.codexworld.com/how-to-guides/add-days-to-date-in-php/)

Answer (score 2):

Even though this is an old question, this way of doing it would take of many situations and seems to be robust. You need to have PHP 5.3.0 or above.

```
$EndDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', "16/07/2017");
$EndDateTime->modify('+6 days');
echo $EndDateTime->format('d/m/Y');
```

You can have any type of format for the date string and this would work.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Set time zone
date_default_timezone_set("asia/kolkata");
$pastdate='2016-07-20';
$addYear=1;
$addMonth=3;
$addWeek=2;
$addDays=5;
$newdate=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($pastdate.' +'.$addYear.' years +'.$addMonth. ' months +'.$addWeek.' weeks +'.$addDays.' days'));
echo $newdate;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use php's date() function, it's not as accurate as the below solution and furthermore it is unreliable in the future.

Use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2016-06-06'); // Y-m-d
$date->add(new DateInterval('P30D'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
?>
```

The reason you should avoid anything to do with UNIX timestamps (`time()`, `date()`, `strtotime()` etc) is that they will inevitably break in the year [2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) due to integer limitations.

The maximum value of an integer is `2147483647` which converts to `Tuesday, 19 January 2038 03:14:07` so come this time; this minute; this second; everything breaks

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

Another example of why I stick to using DateTime is that it's actually able to calculate months correctly regardless of what the current date is:

```
$now = strtotime('31 December 2019');

for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
    echo date('d M y', strtotime('-' . $i .' month', $now)) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

You'd get the following sequence of dates:

```
31 December
31 November
31 October
31 September
31 August
31 July
31 June
```

PHP conveniently recognises that three of these dates are illegal and converts them into its best guess, leaving you with:

```
01 Dec 19
31 Oct 19
01 Oct 19
31 Aug 19
31 Jul 19
01 Jul 19
```