# loop to generate the last ten mondays from today

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a chart to show student progress, showing only the last handful of weeks (mondays) as m/d.
Here is what I've tried:

```
$here = date( 'W', strtotime('this Monday'));
$then = date('W', strtotime('-70 days', strtotime('this Monday')));
    for($i = $then; $i<=$here; $i++)
    {
        $temp = date('W', strtotime($i));
        $tempa = strtotime($temp);
        $newd = date('m/d', $tempa);
        list .=",".$newd);
    }
```

this current iteration gives me a series of 01/01.
Can someone help?
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [generating dates of previous seven days in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2337968/generating-dates-of-previous-seven-days-in-php)

Comment: Are you sure about that code? I've spotted at least two syntax errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use PHP's [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class.

```
<?php 
$nextMonday = new \DateTime(date('Y-m-d') . ' previous Monday');
echo "<br/>" . $nextMonday->format('Y-m-d');
for ($i=1 ; $i<=9 ; ++$i) {
 $nextMonday->sub(new DateInterval('P7D'));
 echo "<br/>" . $nextMonday->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

**Output:**

```
2019-04-22
2019-04-15
2019-04-08
2019-04-01
2019-03-25
2019-03-18
2019-03-11
2019-03-04
2019-02-25
2019-02-18
```

[See it live here](https://3v4l.org/FPis2)

**Code Explained:**

- First get previous Monday.
- Now, add loop for 1 to 9 (We already have recent Monday).
- In the loop, subtract date by 7 days (P -> Period, 7D -> 7 Days)
- By this, we can step over to only Mondays and (Monday to Monday) is 7 days difference.
- It will print last 10 Mondays (1 before and 9 after the loop).

Comment: Fabulous.  I tried other similar questions, but I couldn't get them to work quite right.  Yours is customizable, so that others will be able to adopt it.

Comment: oops, ....er....how do I reverse this order? It actually will be one big string, like "02-18,02-25,03-04,03-11,03-18,03-25" ..etc.

Comment: Replace `$nextMonday->sub(new DateInterval('P7D'));` by `$nextMonday->add(new DateInterval('P7D'));`

Answer (score 0):

```
$thisMonday = strtotime('this Monday');
$lastMonday = $thisMonday - 86400 * 7; //a day has 86400 seconds
$secondLastMonday = $thisMonday - 86400 * 14;
```

.....
and so on!