# php - add + 7 days to date format mm dd, YYYY

Tags: php, datetime

I have date of this format March 3, 2011 in database and I need to extend it with 7 days. I mean

```
 $date = $date + 7
```

. Is there any build in function to do that ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add number of days to a date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332681/add-number-of-days-to-a-date)

Comment: What format is the date type in your DB? Your best bet will be to pull the data out and run it through your own function, increment the additional days to the string and then pop it back into the DB.

Comment: and many more in http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=add+7+days+date+php

Answer (score 159, accepted):

```
$date = "Mar 03, 2011";
$date = strtotime($date);
$date = strtotime("+7 day", $date);
echo date('M d, Y', $date);
```

Comment: is there also anyway to compare the final form with the today date ? (e.g if ($date < current date) {echo ' the date is in the past' }?

Comment: @Michael the result of strtotime is an integer. This integer represents the number of seconds since the UNIX epoch (Jan 1 1970 00:00:00). These integers can be compared using the exact code you just used.

Comment: @Michael the `time()` function can be used to get the current date/time as a UNIX timestamp for comparison.

Comment: yeah you're right .. anyway I used strtotime("now") instead of time()

Answer (score 25):

## The "+1 month" issue with strtotime

As noted in several blogs, strtotime() solves the "+1 month" ("next month") issue on days that do not exist in the subsequent month differently than other implementations like for example MySQL.

```
$dt = date("Y-m-d");
echo date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( "$dt +1 day" ) ); // PHP:  2009-03-04
echo date( "Y-m-d", strtotime( "2009-01-31 +2 month" ) ); // PHP:  2009-03-31
```

Answer (score 22):

`echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime('+7 days'));`

Comment: Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 21):

Another more recent and object style way to do it :

```
$date = new DateTime('now');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P7D'));
```

[php doc of datetime add](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

Comment: To convert to string do: $dateString = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

Answer (score 5):

yes

```
$oneweekfromnow = strtotime("+1 week", strtotime("<date-from-db>"));
```

on another note, why do you have your date in the database like that?

Answer (score 0):

```
onClose: function(selectedDate) {

    $("#dpTodate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
    var maxDate = new Date(selectedDate);

     maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate() + 6); //6 days extra in from date

     $("#dpTodate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", maxDate);
}
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

> $date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("+7 days", strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))));