# PHP - Adding 7 days to a date the proper way

Tags: php, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add number of days to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332681/add-number-of-days-to-a-date)

I'm writing a function to insert the current date into the database, the code I use for that is

```
$data['created']    = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

What I also want to do is add the date 7 days ahead of the current date.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332681/add-number-of-days-to-a-date?