# Add days to a date in PHP

Tags: php, function, date

Is there any php function available where I can add days to a date to make up another date? For example, I have a date in the following format:
27-December-2011

If I add 7 to the above, it should give:
03-January-2012.

Many thanks

Comment: You [have not looked around for answers much](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=add+days+to+php+date), have you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add number of days to a date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332681/add-number-of-days-to-a-date)

Comment: depends how the date is stored, but in any case take a look at the date() and date_parse() functions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this

```
$add_days = 7;
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date) + (24*3600*$add_days));
```

Comment: @user1038814 ehh, how bout `date('y-m-d', strtotime('+' . $add_days . ' days'))`

Comment: maybe you meant `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date.' +' . $add_days . ' days'))`.  should work this too

Comment: No, it is not necessary to put the current date in the strtotime() string. '+5 days' will return the date that is 5 days from now.

Comment: but that is not what the person wants, they want a $date plus 5 days.  for example adding 7 days to the string `27-December-2011`

Comment: ah I see. In that case I might use the second argument of strtotime(), which allows you to enter an arbitrary time for what "now" is.

Comment: Completely forgot about that, but you would end up calling strtotime twice `strtotime('+'.$add_days.' days',strtotime($date))`

Answer (score 9):

Look at this simple snippet

```
$date = date("Y-m-d");// current date

$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 day");
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 week");
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +2 week");
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +1 month");
$date = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date)) . " +30 days");
```

Comment: This is entirely incorrect. As is, this returns a time integer. The outermost strtotime needs to be removed and the " + x days" moved inside the inner strtotime function. Ex: $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date . " +30 days"));

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [add](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) method of DateTime. Anyway this solution works for php version >= 5.3

Comment: Wow, thats better then using _strtotime()_. Didn't know it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+6 days', strtotime($original_date)));
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's  easier than all that.

```
$some_var = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+7 day"))
```

You can use a variable instead of the string, of course. It will be great if the people answering the questions, won't complicate things. Less code, means less time to waste on the server ;).

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = new DateTime('27-December-2011');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P7D'));
echo $date->format('d-F-Y') . "\n";
```

Change the format string to be whatever you want. (See the documentation for `date()`).

Answer (score 0):

```
$registered = $udata->user_registered;
$registered = date( "d m Y", strtotime( $registered ));
$challanexpiry = explode(' ', $registered);
$day   = $challanexpiry[0];
$month = $challanexpiry[1];
$year  = $challanexpiry[2];
$day = $day+10;
$bankchallanexpiry = $day . " " . $month . " " . $year;
```