# Increase current date by 5 days

Tags: php, date

```
$date = date('Y-m-d',current_time('timestamp', 0));
```

How do I change `$date` to `$date + 5 days`?

PHP version is 5.2.

This code doesn't work:

```
$date_cur = date('Y-m-d',current_time('timestamp', 0));
echo $date_cur . ' <br>';
$date_cur_plus = date($date_cur, strtotime('+5 days'));
echo $date_cur_plus;
```

Gives me:

```
2011-11-29 
2011-11-29
```

Comment: duplicate of all of those http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=add+days+php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add number of days to a date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332681/add-number-of-days-to-a-date)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use `mktime()` using the timestamp.

Something like:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d') + 5, date('Y')));
```

Using `strtotime()` is faster, but my method still works and is flexible in the event that you need to make lots of modifications.  Plus, `strtotime()` can't handle ambiguous dates.

**Edit**

If you have to add 5 days to an already existing date string in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`, then you could split it into an array and use those parts with `mktime()`.

```
$parts = explode('-', $date);
$datePlusFive = date(
    'Y-m-d', 
    mktime(0, 0, 0, $parts[1], $parts[2] + 5, $parts[0])
    //              ^ Month    ^ Day + 5      ^ Year
);
```

Comment: How do I make new variable +5 days from $date_cur?

Comment: Where are you getting method `current_time()` from? try using `time()`.

Comment: `$date_cur_plus = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+5 days'));`

Comment: I have to increase the variable, because it is stored in database.

Comment: Gotcha. Check my edit which has been modified per your question.

Answer (score 40):

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+5 days'));
```

Comment: I mean date($date_cur, strtotime('+5 days')); gives the same result, as the $date_cur

Comment: I suggest you check how does date function work - http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 5):

Object oriented Style:

```
<?php
    $date = new DateTime('now');
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P5D'));
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
?>
```

Procedural Style:

```
<?php
    $date = date_create('2016-01-01');
    date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('5 days'));
    echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
?>
```

Comment: @matino has the nicest procedural answer, but I like this OOP one very much.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime):

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+5 days'));
```

Comment: how to add 5 days in a given date @phihag

Answer (score 4):

For specific date:

```
$date = '2011-11-01';
$date_plus = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date.'+5 days'));
echo $date.'<br>'.$date_plus;
```

It will be give :

```
2011-11-01
2011-11-06
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$dateplus5 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+5 days'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
strtotime(“+5 days”)
```

to get the current date plus 5 days or

```
$targetDate = date($date, strtotime(’+5 days’));
```

Answer (score 2):

`strtotime()` is very nice. It allows you to do the following:

```
$startDate = 'now'; // or choose a certain date you want/have
$startDate = '2013-02-14';
$intervals = array(
    '', 
    '+ 5 days', 
    '+ 31 days', 
    '+ 3 months', 
    '+ 2 years + 2 days'
); 
foreach($intervals as $interval) {
    $combinedDate = $startDate . ' ' . $interval;
    var_dump($combinedDate . ' => ' date('Y-m-d', strtotime($combinedDate)));
}
```

with a result:

> now  => 1360334498 = 2013-02-08
>
> now  + 5 days => 1360766498 = 2013-02-13
>
> now  + 31 days => 1363012898 = 2013-03-11
>
> now  + 3 months => 1368020498 = 2013-05-08
>
> now  + 2 years + 2 days => 1423579298 = 2015-02-10

or:

> 2013-02-14  => 1360792800 = 2013-02-14
>
> 2013-02-14  + 5 days => 1361224800 = 2013-02-19
>
> 2013-02-14  + 31 days => 1363471200 = 2013-03-17
>
> 2013-02-14  + 3 months => 1368478800 = 2013-05-14
>
> 2013-02-14  + 2 years + 2 days => 1424037600 = 2015-02-16

Answer (score 0):

I used this:

```
$date = strtotime("+1 day", strtotime("2007-02-28"));
echo date("Y-m-d", $date);
```

It's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Did not supposed to be like this?

```
$date_cur = date('Y-m-d', current_time('timestamp', 0));
echo $date_cur . ' <br>';
$date_cur_plus = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+5 days', current_time('timestamp', 0) ) );
echo $date_cur_plus;
```

Answer (score 0):

if the date is already exists, you can used this code :

```
$tartDate = date("m/d/Y", strtotime("+1 Day", strtotime($Date)));
```