# Add days to date variable

Tags: php, mysql, date, strtotime

I am trying to add days and/or weeks to a date that is being pulled from a database. All I am getting is the 12-31-1969 default date when it cannot output correctly. Here is my code:

```
$lastFeed = "6-25-2013"; //pulled from database last feed date 

$feedSchedule = "2"; //pulled from database number of weeks.

$nextFeeding = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($lastFeed . ' + ' . $feedSchedule. ' week'));
```

I have also tried multiplying the days times the $feedSchedule variable and replacing week(s) with day(s).

Comment: Sorry that was a typo I have edited it to replace it with $lastFeed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332681/add-number-of-days-to-a-date

Comment: I am trying to add days/weeks to a specific pulled time, not today's date which your link suggest.

Comment: have you echo/print your retrieved `$lastFeed` variable to ensure that your year is not being retrieved as 0000 which would return 12-31-1969

Comment: I have. I just tried to format it using to see if it would output the same date("m-d-Y", strtotime($lastFeed)); and I'm getting the 1969 date.

Comment: echo just the retrieved MySQL value, I bet that you are getting something similiar to `00-00-0000`

Comment: I am not I have echoed the MySQL value and it is indeed showing the 6-25-2013 value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code that will work and account for the invalid [Date Time String](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)

```
function nextFeeding($lastFeed,$feedSchedule){
  //fix date format
  $correctedDate = explode("-",$lastFeed);
  //pad month to two digits may need to do this with day also
  if($correctedDate[0] < 10 && strlen($correctedDate[0])!==2){
    $correctedDate[0] = "0".$correctedDate[0];
  }
  $correctedDate = $correctedDate[2]."-".$correctedDate[0]."-".$correctedDate[1];
  //get the next feeding date
  $nextFeeding = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($correctedDate . ' + ' . $feedSchedule. ' week'));
  //return value
  return $nextFeeding;
}

$lastFeed = "6-25-2013"; //pulled from database last feed date 

$feedSchedule = "2"; //pulled from database number of weeks.

$nextFeeding = nextFeeding($lastFeed,$feedSchedule);
echo $nextFeeding;
```

returns

```
07-09-2013
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put the semicolon on the third line... just tried it in PHP sandbox and all works!

Comment: I placed the semicolon there because I noticed it as well. It still does not work.

Comment: try this before running the conversion `echo $lastFeed;` and let me know exactly what you are getting.

Comment: I am running this without a conversion. $lastFeed when echoed shows the correct format of 6-25-2013 and then $lastFeed is then used in your function. Once the function is run it shows the date as 12-31-1969. $feedschedule varies each time it is used. On one animal it is 2 on the other it can be 10.

Comment: I did put in the date and the raw number instead of a variable and it returned it just fine.

Comment: can you edit your question to include all of your code including mysql query... please remember security though and do not include your database credentials... I believe you may have a typo with a variable somewhere if it works when you define the variable hard coded vs defining it with your mysql query

Comment: I echoed the $correctedDate after the conversion in the function and it is showing a formated 6-25-2013 from the variable as 2013-006-25. Any ideas?

Comment: I have verified that I am pulling the MySQL data correctly and echoed/printed it onto the webpage successfully. It is going through your function but is not adding the weeks to the date successfully.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32354/discussion-between-amaster507-and-n-starnes)

Answer (score 2):

`6-25-2013` is not a valid date format. Try `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: The date format I am using works fine and for the purpose it is serving. I have used it in the past and on previous lines of code with this application.

Comment: @n_starnes But as you have observed, it doesn't work as an input format for `strtotime()`. You don't have to switch the format globally, but you will need to modify it for use with `strtotime()`.

Comment: doing it as you suggest displays: 1969-Dec-Wed I need accurate date information not day of the week.