# Adding days to a certain date

Tags: php, mysql, date, addition

I got this date that I want to add a certain amount of days.
I try to change this:

```
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row_RSacessorios['Data_pedido']. ' + 10 days'));
```

Into this:

```
$numDays = $row_RSacessorios['Dias'];
echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row_RSacessorios['Data_pedido']. ' + ' . $numDays . ' days'));
```

My result is the same all the time "1-1-1970"

If I assume $numDays = 12 it gives me the correct date.
mySQL date format is yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: So what is `$row_RSacessorios['Data_pedido']`?  You have that as the first part in strtotime and as the second part (in the second code part).  `$numDays` should be some sort of number but you seem to imply it is a date.  So you are adding two dates as far as I can tell.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332681/add-number-of-days-to-a-date

Comment: Can you please output the $row_RSacessorios['Data_pedido'] data?, the problem should be around that.

Comment: sorry $numDays = $row_RSacessorios['Dias'];

Comment: Ok, but what are both of those variables?  What are the actual values?

Comment: $numDays int 12 and $row_RSacessorio['Data_pedido'] date 2013-04-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small test.

```
$num = '10';

var_dump(date('d-m-Y', strtotime("+ $num days")));

$testDate = date('d-m-Y');

var_dump(date('d-m-Y', strtotime($testDate. " + $num days")));
```

After your comment Update,

```
$num = 12;
$testDate = '2013-04-10';
var_dump(date('d-m-Y', strtotime($testDate. " + $num days")));
```

You gave us this information, which works.

Please check your $row_RSacessorios['Data_pedido'] and $days variable.

Example:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/6OytfB

http://codepad.viper-7.com/Kgb7BX (after)

Answer (score -2):

```
$date = strtotime("+ ". $numDays . " day", $date);
```

could try this. i saw it on a different post

My guess is that strtotime has certain parameter order.. so if you put:

```
strtotime("+# days", $var);
```

it should work

Comment: Please don't guess, there's a [man page for that](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.strtotime.php).