# Get +30 days from timestamp (PHP)

Tags: php, date, unix-timestamp

Here is my code:

```
$graceperiod = strtotime("+30 day","23-12-2013");
echo $graceperiod;
```

I get the following output:

```
Sat, 31 Jan 1970 00:00:23 GMT
```

The year is wrong. Any idea why it is not converting properly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add number of days to a date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332681/add-number-of-days-to-a-date)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

strtotime is a "dangerous" function if you don't know what it does exactly.
You should try it like this

```
strtotime('+30 days', $timestamp);
```

Where $timestamp is an actual timestamp, because it's not as reliable as you may wish

Comment: only works it seems when I put an actual timestamp in.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you put in a timestamp or a variable filled with a timestamp as PHP is not relying on types. But a timestamp or  datetype is always more reliable than a stringified representatiopn of that variable

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime` takes the Unix timestamp as its second parameter, so you need to convert it first.

The following has the correct output:

```
$graceperiod = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+30 days",strtotime("23-12-2013")));
echo $graceperiod;
```

Comment: If you have a fixed date string like `23-12-2013`, `strtotime('23-12-2013 +30 days');` would also work.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the good old `strtotime()` function (which accepts a timestamp as second parameter) or use the `DateTime` classes:

Using `strtotime()`

```
$format = 'd-m-Y';

$timestamp = strtotime( "+30 day",strtotime( "23-12-2013" ) );
echo date( $format, $timestamp );
```

Using `DateTime` classes:

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat( $format, '23-12-2013' );
$dateTime->add( new DateInterval( 'P30D' ) );
echo $dateTime->format( $format );
```

Here the `P30D` means a period of 30 days

One advantage of using `DateTime` is you can define [your own format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#refsect1-datetime.createfromformat-parameters) instead of using from the [list of accepted formats](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) for `strtotime()`

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$graceperiod = strtotime("+30 day","23-12-2013");
```

to

```
$graceperiod = strtotime("+30 days","23-12-2013");
```

`30 days` is correct instead of `30 day`

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` takes second parammeter as timestamp, so you should do:

```
$graceperiod = strtotime("+30 day", strtotime("23-12-2013"));
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $graceperiod);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
$date = "23-12-2013";
$graceperiod = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+30 days",strtotime($date)));
echo $graceperiod;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strtotime("next month");
```

or

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+30 days"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
$graceperiod = strtotime('23-12-2013 +30 day');
var_dump(date('Y-m-d', $graceperiod));
```

Result:

```
string(10) "2014-01-22"
```