# Increment date when it should be a new month

Tags: php, date

I have a PHP script which records things based on the day.  So it will have a weekly set of inputs you would enter.

I get the data correctly, but when i do `$day ++;` it will increment the day, going passed the end of the month without ticking the month.

example:

```
//12/29
//12/30
//12/31
//12/32
//12/33
```

Where it should look like

```
//12/29
//12/30
//12/31
//01/01
//01/02
```

My script is as follows:

```
$week = date ("Y-m-d", strtotime("last sunday"));
$day = $week;
$run = array(7);  //this is actually defined in the data posted to the script, which is pretty much just getting the value of the array index for the query string.
foreach( $run as $key=>$value)
{
    $num = $key + 1;
    $items[] = "($num, $user, $value, 'run', '$day')";
    echo "".$day;
    $day ++;
}
```

Should I be manipulating the datetime differently for day incrementations?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332681/add-number-of-days-to-a-date
and that linked question has some code that will probably help you as well

Comment: I am trying to see this being the thing.  it seems to set it correct and shows the `$day` as `2015-12-29` which makes sense, but it wont tick to the next month when incrementing.... So it will say:  `2015-12-32`   Its still a date object, so im not sure why it wont just work accordingly.

Comment: `$day` is not a datetime, it is a string. So adding 1 to it is not going to give you the results you're looking for.

Comment: Try having a check that says something like: `$day == 30 ? $day = 1 : $day++;`

Comment: what about something like: `$day = strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($day));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You refer to `$day` as a "datetime" but it is just a string - that is what `date()` returns.  So when you do `$day++` you are adding `1` to `"2015-12-02"`. PHP will do everything it can to make `"2015-12-02"` into a number and then add `1` to it, which is not date math. Here is a simple example:

```
<?php
$name = "Fallenreaper1";
$name++;
echo $name
?>
```

This will output:

```
Fallenreaper2
```

This is how I would do it, using an appropriate data type ([`DateTime`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)):

```
<?php
$day = new DateTime('last sunday');

$run = array(7);
foreach ($run as $key => $value) {
  $num = $key + 1;
  $dayStr = $day->format('Y-m-d');
  $items[] = "($num, $user, $value, 'run', '$dayStr')";
  echo $dayStr;
  $day->modify('+1 day');
}
```

Comment: Im thinking this is more efficient than doing a bunch of `strtotime` then, right?

Comment: `modify()` is probably just calling `strtotime` under the hood, so I doubt it.

Comment: ahh ok.  I like both answers, just not sure which is "right"

Comment: My personal preference is to always use `DateTime` and friends when dealing with date/time manipulation. But to each their own.

Comment: i thought i was using datetime, so i think this will be labelled as the correct answer, to make sure my code makes sense and is clean instead of looking like a datetime, but being a string.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
$day = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($day . " +1 day"));
```

instead of

```
$day++;
```

See [live demo in ideone](https://ideone.com/ZrglPa)

Answer (score 0):

To increase time you should use strtotime("+1 day");

here is simple example of using it

```
<?php
$now_time = time();
for($i=1;$i<8;$i++) {
    $now_time = strtotime("+1 day", $now_time);
    echo date("Y-m-d", $now_time) . "<br>";
}
?>
```