# How to Add Two Days from Current Date to the Value of a Hidden Input

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code and I want to add two days from the current date to the value of a hidden input.  If I borrow now, this results in a waiting period of two days.  It will be better if I borrow on Friday; Saturdays and Sundays will not count so the waiting period ends on Monday, four days later.

```
<input type="hidden" name="due_date" id="sd" maxlength="10" style="border: 3px double #CCCCCC;" required/>
```

Comment: You can do it using Javascript... Or the backend language you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code creates an array of objects referring to the days of the week as well as a Date object oDate used to retrieve the current date information.  If the day of the week is not Friday, then user is advised to wait till Friday.

The hidden input "due_date" has its value set to two days from the current date unless that day is Friday in which case the due date becomes 4 days later, to skip the weekend and add the usual 2 days to the waiting period.  If the hidden input were part of a form, once it is submitted, and the data validated, assuming submission by POST, one could use variable $_POST["due_date"] in an INSERT query to store that value in a database, making sure to use either [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo) and bound parameters.

Note: I altered the HTML so that both the NAME and ID attributes of the hidden input are both set to "due_date".

```js
var d = document;
d.g = d.getElementById;

var arrDaysOfWeek = {"Sunday":0,"Monday":1,"Tuesday":2,"Wednesday":3,"Thursday":4,"Friday":5,"Saturday":6};

var arrWkDayNames = Object.keys( arrDaysOfWeek );

var oDate = new Date();
var currDay = oDate.getDay();

var md = oDate.getDate();
var mm = oDate.getMonth() + 1;
var y =  oDate.getFullYear();


var waitPeriod = 2;  // default

var daysTillFriday = (currDay == 0)? arrDaysOfWeek["Friday"]
: arrDaysOfWeek["Friday"] - currDay;

if (currDay == arrDaysOfWeek["Saturday"]) {
   daysTillFriday = arrWeekDayNames.length + arrDaysOfWeek["Friday"] - currDay;
}

var mess = "";

if (currDay != arrDaysOfWeek["Friday"] ) {
    mess = "\nYou should wait to borrow on Friday, i.e. " + daysTillFriday + " days from today.";
}

if( currDay + 2 != arrDaysOfWeek["Friday"] ) {
 daysTillFriday = arrDaysOfWeek["Friday"] - currDay - 2;
 
  mess += "\nSo, best not even in two days. Just wait till Friday which will be in " + daysTillFriday  + " days from two days from now.";
  
}

waitPeriod = (currDay == arrDaysOfWeek["Friday"] )
? 4 //skip sat. & sun. plus 2
: 2; // usual wait period


oDate.setDate(md + waitPeriod);


mess += "\nTo proceed know that the happening date is " + oDate;

//USA date style ...
var date_parts = [ mm, md, y ];

mess += "\nToday is " + arrWkDayNames[ currDay ] + ", " + date_parts.join("/");

d.g("display").textContent = mess;

d.g("due_date").value = oDate;
console.log( "Hidden input due date value: " +  d.g("due_date").value );
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>

<input type="hidden" name="due_date" id="due_date" maxlength="10" style="border: 3px double #CCCCCC;" required/>
```

Comment: How can I get the value and insert that into database? because It doesn't display the name="due_date" is in my database so when I press Borrow It should save in database but I don't know how to pass the value that you wrote for me thank you my friend

Comment: My friend I don't know how to use javascript and pass it to php can you do it for me? Sorry for my request I'll just don't know what to do in webstorage

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to add 2 days and For Friday(5) add 4 days to skip Saturday And Sunday plus 2 days:

```js
var currentDate = new Date();

//Checking If Current day is Friday

if(currentDate.getDay() == 5) {
    var numberOfDaysToAdd = 4; //Adding 4 to skip sat. & sun. if Friday
} else {
    var numberOfDaysToAdd = 2; //Adding 2 days if not Friday
}
currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);

//Formatting to dd/mm/yyyy :

var dd = currentDate.getDate();
var mm = currentDate.getMonth() + 1;
var y = currentDate.getFullYear();

var someFormattedDate = dd + '/'+ mm + '/'+ y;

// Displaying Fromatted Date

document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = someFormattedDate;
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
```

It has been assumed that nothing is Borrowed on Saturday And Sunday.

Comment: Well what will I do in my input hidden? I already put div id="display" and in input hidden does not get the value of currentDate what should I do? thank you my friend

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript, no jQuery required:

```
var someDate = new Date();
var numberOfDaysToAdd = 2;
someDate.setDate(someDate.getDate() + numberOfDaysToAdd);
```

Formatting to dd/mm/yyyy :

```
var dd = someDate.getDate();
var mm = someDate.getMonth() + 1;
var y = someDate.getFullYear();

var someFormattedDate = dd + '/'+ mm + '/'+ y;
```

> answer from - [How to add number of days to today's date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818193/how-to-add-number-of-days-to-todays-date)

You can do it in php

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+2 days"));
```

> Answer From - [Add number of days to a date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332681/add-number-of-days-to-a-date)