# php date function to find days of current week

Tags: php, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Increase days to php current Date()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277247/increase-days-to-php-current-date)

i was wondering how can i make a look that will print out toodays day and all the days for the following 7 days. 
I am using somthingh like this ``` date("m.d.y")+1;``date("m.d.y")+2; ``` ect 
How can i make a loop that will wriet this out in a decent format ? 
Thanks for the time in advanced

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i=1; $i<=7; $i++) echo date("m.d.y", time() + (86400 * $i));
```

Comment: The answer is technically wrong because [not all days have 86400 seconds](http://hpiers.obspm.fr/eop-pc/).

Comment: @hakre care to share an example?

Comment: Try to get `2012 June 30, 23h 59m 60s` (not within the next 7 but 8 days), see ftp://hpiers.obspm.fr/iers/bul/bulc/bulletinc.dat