# How to set input field's max date from current date

Tags: javascript, php, forms, date

```
 <input type="date" name="date" min=
     <?php
         echo date('Y-m-d');
     ?>
 >
```

I want users to select a date between current date to next 7 days. This input min disables past dates from current date . Now how can I set the max limit next 7 days from current date?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `max` attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try adding the `max` attribute to the input but be aware that this can be modified in the browser.

```
<input type="date" name="date" min="<?=date('Y-m-d');?>" max="<?=date('Y-m-d',strtotime('now +1 week'));?>" />
```

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You could try by adding:

```
max=
 <?php
     echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+7 days'));
 ?>
```

?

[Increase days to php current Date()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277247/increase-days-to-php-current-date)