# Get next 2 days not counting current day in PHP

Tags: php, strtotime, date-math

I have an Unix timestamp like this 1660293621 (2022-08-12 8:40). I want to get next 2 days not counting current date. I expect the result to be 2022-08-15 00:00.
I tried

```
strtotime("+3 Days", $current_date)
```

but it returns 2022-08-15 8:40, not 00:00

How can I get that in PHP? Thank you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, just add 0:00 will help

```
$next2days = strtotime("+3 days 0:00", $current_date);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
$Today=date('y:m:d');

// add 3 days to date
$NewDate=Date('y:m:d', strtotime('+3 days'));
```

Reference:
[Increase days to php current Date()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277247/increase-days-to-php-current-date)

Comment: This is not the result I want. Becasue the hour remains 8:40, not 00:00